# Confused about ThymeleafConfig in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I added a ThymeleafConfig to my Spring Boot application so I could configure the template mode to HTML5. Prior to adding it, the Spring Boot application could find the home.html template. After adding it now I get a:

```
 org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

My directory structure is a standard resources/templates/home.html

Here is my ThmyeleafConfig:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver defaultTemplateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I've followed what the examples are doing but there's obviously something I've missed. Any suggestions how I can fix this so it finds the templates properly?

Comment: Why would you need to add this? Thyme leaf is already configured for you by Spring Boot?

Comment: It is, but the problem was that angularjs directives like <body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak layout="column"> were failing parsing. So the suggestion I saw was to set mode to LEGACYHTML5 or HTML5 rather than the default. I'll try what Andy showed below but I'm open to other solutions and would be interested to know what specifically I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to declare your own beans. You can configure the mode using application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```